# Chalice and Peewee, Error by calling different view

Tags: peewee, chalice

I have the following chalice app:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from chalice import Chalice
from models import ContentItem

app = Chalice(app_name='moderations')
app.debug = True


@app.route("/item/{item_id}", methods=['GET'])
def view_item(item_id):
    instance = ContentItem.get(ContentItem.id == item_id)
    return model_to_dict(instance)

@app.route("/item/{item_id}", methods=['POST'])
def save_item(item_id):
    request = app.current_request
    data = request.json_body
    instance = ContentItem.get(ContentItem.id == item_id)
    instance.content = data
    instance.save()
    return


def model_to_dict(instance):
    data = {'content': instance.content, 'id': instance.id}
    return data
```

And I am running `chalice local`

When to go to GET `http://localhost:8000/item/1234`, I get the record fine
But then if I go to POST `http://localhost:8000/item/1234`, nothing happens, just sits there waiting ...

If I post first, which will work fine, then get the detail page, which results the same waiting game.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: PS. I raised the issue on the repo here https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/628

Answer (score 0):

The connection is not closed properly. `before_request` and `after_request` not supported by chalice yet. So we need to close the connection as it finish.

I suggest to use [ExecutionContext](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#ExecutionContext) to create separate connecton for the each exection.

```
@app.route("/item/{item_id}", methods=['GET'])
def view_item(item_id):

    with db.execution_context():
        # This statement is executed using the new `ctx_conn`.
        instance = ContentItem.get(ContentItem.id == item_id)
    return model_to_dict(instance)
```

Comment: @coleifer thanks for the edit. you're right. And did you noticed the `with` indent. I wrongly indent that.

Comment: I assume we would not need this when deployed to AWS Lambda right?